# Is it possible to download several of my photo albums at once PickNZip?

Tags: facebook

I use [PickNZip](http://www.picknzip.com/) to retrieve some of my pictures I uploaded on Facebook. Is it possible to download several of my photo albums at once on PickNZip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to download several photo albums at once using PickNZip.